# My trading platform adjusted the minimum trade size according to my balance. Is this legal?

Tags: trading, scams, legal, cyprus

I started trading in a platform.  When my balance was small, the gap between buy and sell (the spread) was tiny.

When I added more funds, the minimum I could buy tripled and the spread increased to 10 times larger.

When I added more funds, the minimum increased again, this time doubling.  I know that it increases  due the balance because I asked customer support.

It seems to me a that they are trying to leave the user with the possibility of being able to just execute 2 or 3 trades, regardless of the cash balance you have. This feels wrong.

**Is it legal to raise the minimum trade?**

Comment: Are you asking if it's legal for a trading platform to allow you to gamble your money away in the markets with just a few trades?  Of course it is.  The responsibility for making or losing money in the markets rests solely with you and not anyone else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I updated the question. I wonder if it's legal to raise the minimum trade according to my balance. It's not about responsibility of the trade, it's about the unannounced and unexplained change of behaviour. Feels like a trickster, changing the game when you win.

Comment: Oh, so the trading platform is now raising the minimum amount required for making a trade, based on your increased balance?  That doesn't sound kosher to me.  I would simply find another trading platform; there are plenty of competitors who would be willing to do business with you without imposing arbitrary rules about how much you must spend on each trade.

Comment: Are you sure this is a legitimate platform and not an out-and-out scam (that will run away with your money when you try to withdraw it)?

Comment: Is this some fly by night unregulated offshore broker?  Bitcoin?  Is it even a legitimate broker?

Comment: They display the company information and a site .gov.cy which I assume is an official government site, verifies its information, apparently they've been running since 2013.

Comment: Unfortunately the mere fact that a company is registered with a foreign government doesn't provide you much protection. If you get ripped off are you prepared to hire an attorney in Cyprus?

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Assuming that site OP is using actually belongs to the company that is registered. https://www.cysec.gov.cy/en-GB/complaints/approved-domains-(1)/ https://www.cysec.gov.cy/en-GB/complaints/non-approved-domains/

Comment: @richardb note the text at the top of the complaint form: "Please kindly note that the Cyprus Securities and Exchange Commission (the ‘CySEC’) does not have restitution powers and **therefore does not investigate individual complaints**. However all complaints submitted to the CySEC are taken into consideration by the CySEC in the performance of its supervisory mandate". In other words, the OP is on his own if he's been ripped off.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant My point was that typosquatting legitimate sites is a thing. I wouldn't even assume that the firm was based in Cyprus without checking the DNS name is the one listed against the company in the CySEC index.

Comment: Spreads go up with larger orders, obviously, since a small order can skim the tip of the spread, but the deeper you dig into the offers the higher the price gets.  The spread is a function of the particular security, though - small cap will have much bigger spreads than high volume large cap.  In any case, spreads growing with trade size is to be expected and normal.  The only real question here is whether it's normal for a broker to restrict your trade sizes based on your account balance.